# Concatenate two lists side by side

Tags: python, list

I am looking for the shortest way of doing the following (one line solution)

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["w", "e", "r"]
```

I want the following output:

```
q = ["a w", "b e", "c r"]
```

Of course this can be achieved by applying a for loop. But I am wondering if there is a smart solution to this?

Comment: import itertools ;print [i for i in itertools.imap((lambda x, y: x+y), a, b)]

Answer (score 9):

You can use `str.join()` and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) , Example -

```
q = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(a,b)]
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> b = ["w", "e", "r"]
>>> q = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(a,b)]
>>> q
['a w', 'b e', 'c r']
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) within a list comprehension :

```
>>> ['{} {}'.format(*i) for i in zip(a,b)]
['a w', 'b e', 'c r']
```

Answer (score 2):

More pythonic way;

```
b = map(' '.join,zip(a,b))
```

Comment: I think list comprehensions are more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["w", "e", "r"]

print(["{} {}".format(_a ,_b) for _a,_b in zip(a,b)])
['a w', 'b e', 'c r']
```

Answer (score 1):

**one line solution:**

```
[aa+" "+bb for aa,bb in zip(a,b)]
```

**output:**

```
['a w', 'b e', 'c r']
```

**one liner without zip:**

```
[a[i]+" "+b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

**output:**

```
['a w', 'b e', 'c r']
```